# Permalinks migration issue

Tags: permalinks

I have a blogging website with over 5000 blogs, with decent traffic and backlinks from the top places.

Right now, the permalinks look like this domain .com/blog-post

Which I want to switch to domain .com/category/blog-post

But, If I am changing the permalinks from the settings, all the old backlinks are showing 404, which means it can hurt the SEO real bad.

Let me know how to make the old domain .com/blog-post automatically redirected to the new domain .com/category/blog-post permalink?

Comment: There are a bunch of ways to do this, either via .htaccess, plugins, or nginx settings depending on your hosting situation. This is a good article to get you started: https://wplift.com/301-redirect-in-wordpress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of tweaking and trying out a new thing, I found a WordPress plugin, which auto redirected all my links to the ones similar to the value set in Dashboard > Settings > Permalinks.

The second solution is to connect your website to Jetpack, and it also solves this problem. If you do not want to go with Jetpack, since it takes many resources, I would suggest going with the first option.

Answer (score -2):

If You want to url domain .com/category/blog-post.
Flow this some steps.

1. Go to Dashboard
2. Setting > permalinks
3. Select option Custom Structure

Then  Available tags: `/%category%/%postname%/`

[image: Settings > Permalinks]

Comment: Hi, My question was about what to do after this (the step you showed), I have already done this. I have like 5000 previous blogs, and they're all showing 404. So, I want to add a mass 404 to them.